# Change apache doc root after OS X update to Sierra

Tags: apache

On Mac. I use a different doc root than default /Library/WebServer/Documents.
So /private/etc/apache/httpd.conf, /private/etc/apache/extra/httpd-ssl.conf and /private/etc/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf set to new doc root.

But every mac update splats these back to default confs. No worries just fix and restart apache.

Except today's update to Sierra. I could not get apache off the default doc root. I edited the default index.html in /Library/WebServer/Documents and saved -- just to be sure it was the one being displayed.

Surprise! It works with the custom doc root.

But how did editing that file fix the problem? I'd like to save some time next mac update!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change file into old document root sudo nano /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en
it works for me, maybe some permission failure after updates.

Comment: A similar idea at 

[link](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083) 

Essentially, copy /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en to /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html then local and user sites will load, then delete the new index.html file and all will be well. 

That .en file has some magic.